# Projection differences in R using sf and sp

Tags: r, projection, coordinate-systems, r-sp, r-sf

I have a grid I have converted from GeoTIFFs to a shapefile. I would like to convert and export the shapefile as a GeoPackage and change the projection so it uses the British National Grid as the geographic coordinate system when opened in a GIS. However this only seems to work using `sp` and not `sf` (which does not appear to retain aspects like the datum).

This is a problem as I would like to export GeoPackages containing multiple layers which you can only currently do in `sf` and not `sp`. Am I doing something wrong?

```
library(rgdal)
library(sf)

download.file("https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1URbux7Sw25KFTySqRFKXk53DV2UK4lsA&export=download" , destfile="Grid_Shapefile.zip")
unzip("Grid_Shapefile.zip")
Grid_sp <- readOGR(".", "Grid_Shapefile")
Grid_sf <- st_as_sf(Grid_sp)

BNG_Grid_sp <- spTransform(Grid_sp, CRS("+init=epsg:27700"))
BNG_Grid_sf_v1 <- st_transform(Grid_sf, crs=27700)
BNG_Grid_sf_v2 <- st_transform(Grid_sf, crs="+init=epsg:27700 +proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=airy +towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.060,0.1502,0.2470,0.8421,-20.4894")

BNG_Grid_sf_v1_geom <- st_geometry(BNG_Grid_sf_v1)
BNG_Grid_sf_v2_geom <- st_geometry(BNG_Grid_sf_v2)

proj4string(BNG_Grid_sp)
attributes(BNG_Grid_sf_v1_geom)
attributes(BNG_Grid_sf_v2_geom)

writeOGR(BNG_Grid_sp, dsn = "BNG_Grid_sp.gpkg", layer = "Grid_sp", driver = "GPKG")
st_write(BNG_Grid_sf_v1, "BNG_Grid_sf_v1.gpkg", "Grid_sf_v1")
st_write(BNG_Grid_sf_v2, "BNG_Grid_sf_v2.gpkg", "Grid_sf_v2")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this (thanks to what Roger has posted [here](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/810)) is using the `lwgeom` package to do the transformation.The post by Roger on the sf GitHub gives further details.

```
library(rgdal)
library(sf)

download.file("https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1URbux7Sw25KFTySqRFKXk53DV2UK4lsA&export=download" , destfile="Grid_Shapefile.zip")
unzip("Grid_Shapefile.zip")
Grid_sp <- readOGR(".", "Grid_Shapefile")
Grid_sf <- st_as_sf(Grid_sp)

library(lwgeom)
BNG_Grid_sf_v4 <- st_transform_proj(Grid_sf, crs="+init=epsg:27700 +proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=airy +towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.060,0.1502,0.2470,0.8421,-20.4894")
st_crs(BNG_Grid_sf_v4)
st_write(BNG_Grid_sf_v4, "BNG_Grid_sf_v4.gpkg", "Grid_sf_v4")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `ogrinfo`, in particular the command

```
ogrinfo BNG*v1.gpkg Grid_sf_v1 > info1
ogrinfo BNG*v2.gpkg Grid_sf_v1 > info2
```

the diff between the two info[1|2] files are, besides the obvious _v1 _v2 naming, this:

```
13c13
<             TOWGS84[446.448,-125.157,542.06,0.15,0.247,0.842,-20.489]],
---
>             TOWGS84[446.448,-125.157,542.06,0.1502,0.247,0.8421,-20.4894]],
```

Are the additional digits in `_v2` causing your troubles in ArcGIS?

Comment: Thanks for looking at this Edzer. However, I don't think that is the problem. The v1 and v2 examples were me testing out different ways of defining the crs using st_transform. v1 uses the epsg code and v2 is where I have used a projection that I know contains a datum. However, the datum does not appear when you try st_crs(BNG_Grid_sf_v1) or st_crs(BNG_Grid_sf_v2). Comparing this to the sp equivalent proj4string(BNG_Grid_sp), which does have a datum, suggests the problem may be that the datum for BNG is not retained by sf when using st_transform and ArcMap can't use something that isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow up on https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/810, not here.